# Qt : no rule to make target after deleting picture

Tags: qt, resource-files

I accidentally permanently deleted one of my picture files today (it was added to the `Qt` resource file earlier) through `File Explorer` (not deleting it via `Qt Creator`). Now whenever I try to build my project, I keep getting a message that says:

```
No rule to make target "mypic.png" needed by "qrcfile.cpp". Stop
```

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Just add the picture again to the correct folder. How to restore an image falls outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 2):

So I think I found the solution to this. All I did was clicking `Clean all`, then `Build All`, then `Run qmake`. After those steps, I tried running the project and it worked!